# Static analysis tool for Java that reports subclassing/implementing specific classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, static-analysis

We just refactored several implementations of ThreadFactory into a single class. I'd like to set up a build which will report if new implementations of ThreadFactory get checked in.

Answer (score 0):

Two solid utilities are:

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Do either have options to configure them to report on illegal subclassing?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make ThreadFactory final if you don't want it to be subclassed? The modifier can be removed if later you decide a subclass is indeed needed.

Comment: It's part of the standard libraries and I don't work for Oracle :)

Comment: Also it's an interface, not an abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom detector for [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/):

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-findbug2/
2. http://www.danielschneller.com/2007/05/findbugs-writing-custom-detectors-part.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JArchitect](http://www.jarchitect.com) for such need.
For that you have to set a baseline from which you want to detect the new implementations and add the following rule using cqlinq

```
from t in Types 
let depth0 = t.DepthOfDeriveFrom("ThreadFactory")
where depth0  == 1 && !t.IsInOlderBuild()
select new { t, depth0 }
```